Почему условная конструкция if работает некоректно?
Не понимаю, в чем проблема, но при присваивании переменной х значения 20 (большее 10), выводится 0, хотя должно быть 10.
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Point point = new Point();
        point.X = 20;
        Console.WriteLine(point.X);
    }
}


 internal class Point
{
    private int x;
    public int X
    {
        get { return x; }
        set 
        {             
            if (value > 10)
            {
                value = 10;
                return;
            }
            if (value < 0) { 
                value = 0;
                return;
            }
            
            x = value; 
        }
    }
}


Так вы делаете return и до строки x = value; ход не доходит, значение переменной x не присваивается.

Присваивайте значение переменной x, а не value, раз уж вы выходите сразу по return и до строки x = value; в конце кода ход не доходит:
            if (value > 10)
            {
                x = 10;
                return;
            }

Либо сделайте так, чтобы это присваивание всегда срабатывало:
            if (value > 10)
            {
                value = 10;
            }
            else if (value < 0) { 
                value = 0;
            }
            x = value; 


x = Math.Clamp(value, 0, 10);

@aepot Ну, можно дальше оптимизировать, да, можно и через switch было коротко тоже сделать. Я просто объяснил, что не так с этим кодом )
